# Something simplier SW tool than Enterprise architect?

Tags: uml, requirements, use-case, rational-unified-process

I'm looking for our (middle sized) project some suitable SW tool for creating and maintaining software requirements specifications. We need to work with both models - requirements model and use case model. I know EA but this tools is too complex for our purposes. Could you recommend me some tips for suitable tools? What do you use?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Visual Studio? It looks like Microsoft has finally decided to conform (in part!) to the UML standard. There are some UML features in VS2010, although not as rich or compliant EA or Magic Draw.

Oh yes, as I mentioned, have a look at Magic Draw - it boasts that it is the only fully UML 2 compliant tool on the market - I can not tell you if this is true or not. I have used it and it is a good UML tool - better than anything that VS2010 can offer.